# getOutputStream() has already been called for this response when I create XLSX file

Tags: java, spring-boot, xlsx

I have some errors when I create my XLSX file. The method below opens a file, modifies this file, and saves the result in another file. This process works, but all the time it shows an error.

This is the method to create and download the file:

```
@RequestMapping("/excelLogbee")
public ModelAndView logbee(HttpServletResponse response) {
    List<Pedido> todosPedidosLogbee = cadastroPedidoService.filtrarLogbee();
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
    try {
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(new File("Template Importacao - Logbee.xlsx")));
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Solicitação");

    int rowCount = 9;
    Row row = sheet.getRow(rowCount);

    for (Pedido pedido : todosPedidosLogbee) {
        row = sheet.getRow(++rowCount);
        row.getCell(4).setCellValue(pedido.getCliente().getNome());
        row.getCell(5).setCellValue(pedido.getCliente().getEndereco() + ", " + pedido.getCliente().getNumeroEndereco());
    }

    Calendar dataHoje = Calendar.getInstance();
    String fileName = "logbee_control_breggion - " + dataHoje.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "-"
            + dataHoje.get(Calendar.MONTH - 1) + "-" + dataHoje.get(Calendar.YEAR) + ".xlsx";
    try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName)) {
        workbook.write(outputStream);
        ClientOutput clientOutput = new ClientOutput(response);
        DownloadHelper.download(clientOutput, "", fileName);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView(PESQUISA_PEDIDO_LOGBEE_VIEW);
    mv.addObject("pedidos", todosPedidosLogbee);
    return mv;
}
```

This is the error:

```
2017-10-18 17:41:27.522 ERROR 9008 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].
[localhost]           : Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, 
location=/error]

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-
```

I try `close()` and `flush()` and did not work.

Comment: You cannot download a file AND render a page. You can do one of those not both at the same time.

Comment: language and no thank you needed